# Android/Linux system is changing the audio drivers on boot with USB mic attached

Tags: audio, linux, usb-drivers

I have logged the proc/asound/cards for sound drivers below. You can see the first one is before I attach the mic array, the second one is after I attach it at runtime, and the third is after rebooting the device.

```
127|Tinker_Board_2:/proc/asound $ cat cards
 0 [hdmisound      ]: hdmi-sound - hdmi-sound
                      hdmi-sound
 1 [rockchipcdndpso]: rockchip-cdndp- - rockchip-cdndp-sound
                      rockchip-cdndp-sound
Tinker_Board_2:/proc/asound $ aplay -l
/system/bin/sh: aplay: inaccessible or not found
127|Tinker_Board_2:/proc/asound $ cat cards                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 0 [hdmisound      ]: hdmi-sound - hdmi-sound
                      hdmi-sound
 1 [rockchipcdndpso]: rockchip-cdndp- - rockchip-cdndp-sound
                      rockchip-cdndp-sound
 2 [ArrayUAC10     ]: USB-Audio - ReSpeaker 4 Mic Array (UAC1.0)
                      SEEED ReSpeaker 4 Mic Array (UAC1.0) at usb-xhci-hcd.1.auto-1.1, full speed
Tinker_Board_2:/proc/asound $ %                                                                                                                                                                                                                          lloydhussell@MAC-Y6XGW6XJ0H Dukebox-Android % adb shell
Tinker_Board_2:/ $ cd proc/asound/                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Tinker_Board_2:/proc/asound $ cat cards
 1 [hdmisound      ]: hdmi-sound - hdmi-sound
                      hdmi-sound
 2 [rockchipcdndpso]: rockchip-cdndp- - rockchip-cdndp-sound
                      rockchip-cdndp-sound
```

It is causing bugs in my applications. So any help on fixing this would be perfect. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was actually in the Android code of my application. I was accessing the interfaces of the USB device and it seemed to corrupt something in the system. I am really not sure why.
Anyway, I just used the interface information provided from the component manufacturer documentation. And instead of iterating through the interfaces to get the one needed for the endpoints, I got the defined ones.